# How to fix Linked Server from SQL Server 2016 to Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I set up a few weeks ago a linked server in my sql server 2016 to my oracle 12c following [this guide](https://logicalread.com/sql-server-2014-and-oracle-12c-linked-servers-mo01/#.WW4pR4jyuUl). It was working properly, but after some windows updates that restarted my machine, it no longer works. I can log into oracle properly through sqlplus and sql developer, but not through sql server. I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LINKED_ORACLE" returned message "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LINKED_ORACLE".
```

I restarted the SQL Server service, as well as restarted windows again, but still same error. What could have changed in a single restart? How can I fix it and get the linked server working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, SQL SERVER was properly reading the tnsnames.ora file before the restart, but after the restart it stopped. I had to recreate the linked server, and put the whole connection string in the Data Source field for it to work again.

Sample Data Source found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2010/06/30/ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified-error-while-creating-a-linked-server-to-oracle/):

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= server01.mydomain.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=OracleDB)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));
```

Comment: You can put `server01.mydomain.com:1521/OracleDB` in Data Source and it will work